# Expand a ScrollView's height programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, scrollview

I'm trying for hours now to solve this issue, doesn't mean it's a difficult one tho because I'm a total beginner.

I'm working with XCode 9 using swift.

I created a ViewController that contains a View that contains a Scroll view.
My goal is to be able to set the simulated height of the scroll view (that I can scroll through) programmatically, so I can make the ScrollView expand.

I tried that:

```
ScrollView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: ScrollView.frame.width, height: 3000)
```

to set the height of the view to 3000, but it isn't working. If I set the height of the view using the storyboard it's working though...

Answer (score 1):

Scrollview expects it's content from inner elements not vice versa , or you need to set it's contentSize like this

```
let scroll = UIScrollView(frame: self.view.frame)

view.addSubview(scroll)

let v1 = UIView(frame: self.view.frame)

v1.backgroundColor = .red

let v2 = UIView(frame: self.view.frame.offsetBy(dx: 0, dy: self.view.frame.height)) // set y of view 2 to be bottom of view 1

v2.backgroundColor = .blue

scroll.addSubview(v1)

scroll.addSubview(v2)

scroll.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height * 2 )
```